# How can I implement a collection with O(1) indexing and mutability in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, asymptotic-complexity

If I'm counting the occurences of characters in a string, I could easily implement this using an array in an imperative language, such as the following:

```
char values[256]; char c;

while (c = readChar()) {
  values[c] += 1;
}
```

I can see how to do this in Haskell using something like `Data.Vector.Mutable`, which provides fast implementation of int-indexed mutable arrays.

**But how could I easily do this using just Haskell with no additional packages and/or extensions?** Of in other words, how can I implement a fast O(1) collection with indexing and mutability?

Comment: @Lee not sure if it's just about accessing the index, since the data structure also needs to be mutable (or provide a way to work around mutability otherwise while keeping the O(1))

Comment: Why do you want to do it without additional packages?  If you want a mutable array that's exactly what `Data.Vector.Mutable` is for!

Comment: @TomEllis Just because there's a library to do something, it doesn't mean you should always use the library. I'm trying to understand how this works underneath and how can I implement it in a simple way myself. Re-implementing a library is the best way to understand how it works.

Comment: @TomEllis Also, I've looked at the source code for Vector, but it's rather large codebase ... so I'm basically looking for the basic idea that enables it to be efficient.

Comment: It probably is implemented through compiler intrinsics. If you wanted to implement something like that yourself, you might need to use FFI - foreign function interface. It's not that hard, but may look weird to a novice.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Frequency of characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21132026/frequency-of-characters)

Comment: @SassaNF Actually if you look at the source of the repo, there is no FFI, it's all pure Haskell https://github.com/haskell/vector

Comment: @josejuan This is **not a duplicate**, the referenced question uses `vector` for a solution. What I'm asking is how to implement a data structure *that has vector-like properties*. Please read the updated title of the question.

Comment: If you want to implement something like this yourself using *only* "base", and no FFI or compiler intrinsics, you can do it by manually allocating and modifying memory. See [`ForeignPtr`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/Foreign-ForeignPtr.html) (or `Ptr` if you want complete control of deallocation).

Comment: You could write the same (imperative) algorithm with [STUArray](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/array-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-Array-ST.html#g:2) from the array package, shipped with GHC, I guess.

Comment: I think you will find it ends up using hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.2.1/docs/src/Data-Primitive-Array.html - here you can see things like `primitive_ (writeArray# arr# i# x)`. I don't know how to parse those, but I bet they come from GHC-specific intrinsics.

Comment: @JakubArnold, your question "How can I implement a collection with O(1) indexing and mutability in Haskell?" is clearly duplicated. *NOW* ("read the updated title") you are asking other thing... (low level implementation or how current packages implement it) :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The implementation of `vector` uses internal GHC functions called primops. You can find them in the package [`ghc-prim`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ghc-prim-0.3.1.0/docs/GHC-Prim.html#g:8) which is hard-wired into GHC. It provides, among others, the following array functions:

```
newArray# :: Int# -> a -> State# s -> (#State# s, MutableArray# s a#) 
readArray# :: MutableArray# s a -> Int# -> State# s -> (#State# s, a#)
writeArray# :: MutableArray# s a -> Int# -> a -> State# s -> State# s
```

These functions are implemented by GHC itself, but they are really lowlevel. The [`primitive`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/primitive-0.5.4.0/docs/Data-Primitive-Array.html) package provides nicer wrappers of these functions. For arrays, these are:

```
newArray :: PrimMonad m => Int -> a -> m (MutableArray (PrimState m) a) 
readArray :: PrimMonad m => MutableArray (PrimState m) a -> Int -> m a 
writeArray :: PrimMonad m => MutableArray (PrimState m) a -> Int -> a -> m ()
```

Here is a simple example using these functions directly (IO is a `PrimMonad`):

```
import Data.Primitive.Array
import Control.Monad

main :: IO ()
main = do
  arr <- newArray 3 (0 :: Int)
  writeArray arr 0 1
  writeArray arr 1 3
  writeArray arr 2 7
  forM_ [0..2] $ \i -> putStr (show i ++ ":") >> readArray arr i >>= print
```

Of course, in practice you would just use the `vector` package, which is much more optimized (stream fusion, ...) and also easier to use.